# Syntax error at or near “case” when using a case statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL query (in PostgreSQL) and I keep getting a syntax error.

```
SELECT data1, data1_class
CASE
    WHEN data1 LIKE '%Bookmarked Removed%' THEN 'Class I'
    ELSE 'Class II'
END
AS data1_class
from events
WHERE event_code = 11
```

The syntax error I get is:

```
  ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CASE"
  LINE 2:     CASE
        ^
  ********** Error **********

  ERROR: syntax error at or near "CASE"
  SQL state: 42601
  Character: 31
```

To me, I don't think that there is an error and this should work however after trying to work it out a few times I can't it to work.

What am I missing from my CASE statement to make it work?

Answer (score 7):

You are missing a comma before the CASE statement. It should be e.g.

```
SELECT data1, data1_class,
CASE
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma before the CASE statement. It should be e.g.

```
SELECT data1, data1_class,
CASE
 ...
```

Though you repeat the data1_class as an alias for your case statement, so perhaps you mean just:

```
SELECT data1,
CASE
  ...
```